# What is this format? PNG unreadable by browser

Tags: png

I got an image, that is supposed to be PNG, but alot of applications can't read it (Windows itself can)... for example Paint Shop Pro says it is incorrect PNG, Chrome or Opera are not reading it neither... What is the problem??

Original image that is not readable by many applications, but is better looking than converted one with GIMP (smoother edges etc etc):

http://creation.pl/img/ok_bad.png

Converted image with GIMP, that does not look that good anymore (raw edges, doesn't look so smooth):

http://creation.pl/img/ok_good.png

How do I make the first one readable without losing quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a mislabelled TIFF file.

The conversion with GIMP seems to have resulted in a darker outline, not sure why, but try using a different conversion software, like [image magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Comment: For a bit of background - the functions used by (most) Windows apps use display routines that do not look at the filename or extension when opening a file and have lots of filetype support.  Chrome  and Opera (which is now basically Chrome in an Opera-gown) clearly don't have (or need) TIFF support.

Comment: :o) Agree. Irfan view actually is a great aplication to find out the real format of a picture, becouse when you open a file with a wrong extension it prompts you to correct it.